# Join two tables after grouping in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables namely, table-A and table-B in a MySQL database. When prod_1 is sold under invoice 102, it will register the quantity in single transaction under invoice 102. If the customer returns two products, it will be registered under table-B under invoice 102 and finally, I'd like to get the difference by deducting the **Sold_Quantity(from table-A) after adding from both Prod_1** of invoice 102 from **Return_Quantity(from table-B)**. Although I'm showing this for a single product but there are over hundreds of products.

The problem is that my sql query is repeatedly deducting from both the invoices, although it should've subtracted **Return_Quantity** of invoice 102 from **Sold_Quantity** of **ONLY** invoice 102.

So the *answer* that I want should be **(4+3)-2 = 5**. 4 and 3 are Sold_Quantity from table-A and 2 is from Return_Quantity from table-B

Can anyone please provide me with the solution in terms of the sql query?

```
 Table-A:
    Invoice_ID | Product_ID | Sold_Quantity
         101        Prod_1          4
         101        Prod_2          5
         102        Prod_1          3

Table-B:
    Invoice_ID | Product_ID | Return_Quantity
        101         Prod_1           2
        101         Prod_2           1
```

Comment: The sql-server tag is about Microsoft SQL Server; you seem to be talking about MySQL so I removed `sql-server`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using inner join and get the result as expected :

```
SELECT      [Table-A].Invoide_ID, [Table-A].Product_ID, [Table-A].Sold_Quantity, 
            [Table-B].Return_Quantity, [Table-A].Sold_Quantity - [Table-B].Return_Quantity 
            AS Rem_Item
FROM        [Table-A] INNER JOIN
            [Table-B] ON [Table-A].Invoide_ID = [Table-B].Invoide_ID
```

Remaining items will be available as `Rem_Item`

[image]

**Edit 1 :**

> So the answer that I want should be **(4+3)-2 = 5**. 4 and 3 are
>   Sold_Quantity from table-A and 2 is from Return_Quantity from table-B

As you have changed your requirement as a whole , let me post the edited query for your reference :

```
SELECT        [Table-A].Product_ID, SUM([Table-A].Sold_Quantity) AS Total_Sold, 
              [Table-B].Return_Quantity, SUM([Table-A].Sold_Quantity) 
                         - [Table-B].Return_Quantity AS Rem_Item
FROM            [Table-A] INNER JOIN
                         [Table-B] ON [Table-A].Product_ID = [Table-B].Product_ID
WHERE        ([Table-A].Product_ID = N'Prod_1')
GROUP BY [Table-B].Return_Quantity, [Table-A].Product_ID
```

[image]

Comment: The answer that I want should be (4+3)-2 = 5. 4 and 3 are Sold_Quantity from table-A and 2 is from Return_Quantity from table-B

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need. it will redeuct only by matching the invoice id

```
SELECT c1.`Invoice_ID` , c1.`Product_ID` , c1.`Sold_Quantity` , c2.Return_Quantity, Sold_Quantity - Return_Quantity AS diff 
FROM tableA c1 
LEFT JOIN tableB c2  
ON c1.Invoice_ID = c2.Invoice_ID
```

Edited Answer. May not be the best one. hope it works

```
SELECT Product_ID , sold-back AS diff
FROM
(
    SELECT c1.`Product_ID` , SUM( `Sold_Quantity` ) AS sold,  
           (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(c2.Return_Quantity), 0)  FROM tableB c2 WHERE c2.Product_ID = c1.Product_ID) AS   back
    FROM `tableA` c1
    GROUP BY c1.`Product_ID`
) t
```

Comment: The answer that I want should be (4+3)-2 = 5. 4 and 3 are Sold_Quantity from table-A and 2 is from Return_Quantity from table-B